# Project Name vs Application Name in Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm trying to create a new Django/Python project in the JetBrains PyCharm IDE.
However, while typing my software name it informs me that

> "You cannot call your app the same as your project".

Trying to fully understand the distinction between projects and applications in Django, I'd love someone to demonstrate the difference between an application and a project for some known compounded websites like Facebook, Gmail and YouTube.

Answer (score 31):

My try with Facebook:

```
facebook
  users
  messages
  notifications
  posts
  ...
```

Basically the gist is that an app represents a specific part of your whole project. Moreover, the app can be "pluggable" into a similar project. In order to be maintainable an app should have it's own objectives that differ from the objectives of other apps.

In the excellent "Two Scoops of Django" [book](https://django.2scoops.org/), the authors quote James Bennett:

> The art of creating and maintaining a good Django app is that it
>   should follow the truncated Unix philosophy according to Douglas
>   McIlroy: "Write programs that do one thing and do it well".

Again the authors state:

> In essence, each app should be tightly focused on its task. If an app
>   can’t be explained in a single sentence of moderate length, or you
>   need to say ‘and’ more than once, it probably means the app is too big
>   and should be broken up.

*Update 19/12/2014*:

With Django 1.7 [this description of "Projects and applications"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#projects-and-applications) is definitely worth reading.

*Update 21/12/2017*:

Django 1.10 link [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#projects-and-applications).

Comment: Hi. Can you give another demonstration, this time for Reddit? This would really help to understand :) Thanks!

Comment: @Reflection If you like my answer then you should upvote it or mark it as correct.

Comment: @Reflection Don't use reddit myself. Why do you need a specific example? As long as you learn to think about this topic then you won't need specific answers.

Comment: I need a specific example just because I'm not so experienced with it.

Comment: @Reflection Just give it a try. As the application evolves you'll notice what you could have done better. One of the best points of Django is that it's so easy to modify what you've already built.

Comment: Okay, you're probably right. However, just to fully understand the concept, I think I need that example for Reddit.

Answer (score 1):

from the tutorial in the docs:

> Projects vs. apps
>   What’s the difference between a project and an app? An app is a Web application that does something – e.g., a Weblog system, a database of public records or a simple poll app. A project is a collection of configuration and apps for a particular Web site. A project can contain multiple apps. An app can be in multiple projects.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models

If you compared it to youtube the whole youtube site could be one big project, with functionality divided in apps such as the video search, messaging, profile/channel creation...if the structure is simpler you can keep different parts in one place, that's up to you. I prefer to only start splitting stuff up down the road.

Answer (score 0):

In the [official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com): 
1) An application is a web application that does something, for example, a blog system 
2) A project is a collection of configuration and applications for a particular web site 
3) A project can contain multiple applications. An application can be in multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

An **application** can be anything that can do some specific task in website. Ex:Banking domain -> Loan application, credit/debit card application etc.

A **project** is a collection of applications for a particular web site. Ex: Banking software, Gmail, Facebook etc.

Refer : https://consideratecode.com/2017/12/29/django-app-project-site/